# Overriding a method returning a reference to an array does not work in gcc, but works in clang/icx

Tags: c++, gcc, clang++

I want to return a reference to an array in C++. I am referring to the `getColor2` member function and its overrides in the example below.

I have a pure virtual member function in my base class `ILed`:

```cpp
[[nodiscard]] virtual const uint8_t (&getColor2() const)[4] = 0
```

I have this method in a sub class `HardwareLed`:

```cpp
[[nodiscard]] const uint8_t (&getColor2() const)[4] override;
```

I'd expect the latter function to override the former, but when using **gcc** (e.g. **13.2**), I get these error message:

```bash
<source>:62:53: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
   62 |   [[nodiscard]] const uint8_t (&getColor2() const)[4] override;
      |                                                     ^
      |                                                      ;
<source>:62:55: error: 'override' does not name a type
   62 |   [[nodiscard]] const uint8_t (&getColor2() const)[4] override;
      |
```

Using the same source code, but with **clang 17.0.1** or **icx 2023.2.1** does not yield these errors and the application compiles successfully.

Here's the complete example: https://godbolt.org/z/d7j7ozKbM

I could just resort to using the raw pointer to the array (perhaps with a struct and a `reinterpret_cast` instruction), but it seems not as good of a solution to me. `getColor` (without the `2`) is implemented that way.

Also I'd file a bug in GCC, but I am not sure if they will let me (GCC bugzilla states, that I'll get an invitation soon?) and they have a lot of known issues and I cannot exactly determine if this is one of them (e.g. incomplete types) as I am a bit of a C++ newbie.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `std::array<uint8_t, 4>`: https://godbolt.org/z/jqPxKeqM8

Comment: There is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473438/return-array-in-a-function and answers with `std::array`. And other https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264304/how-to-return-an-array-from-a-function, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808825/c-function-to-return-array, you may pick a dupe.

Comment: *No wonder people prefer AI bots instead of asking on SO* -- The problem with using AI bots, especially for C++, is that for the most part, the answers are nonsense or just plain gibberish.  So it's a choice of getting a totally screwed up answer that looks ok to a newbie, or putting the time in reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and then asking a question according to those guidelines.

Comment: [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so what exactly wasn't "good" about my question? I did some research, but either I wasn't experienced enough to determine, that a question+answer was basically what I was looking for - or there is none (which I doubt, but could be?). Also `std::array` is not a proper answer nor is it equivalent enough (you - at least somewhat - lose the obvious limitation to just 4 elements) and besides some AI bot suggested that to me, too, but my intent was a bit different and @Weijun Zhou 's response shows what I meant.

Comment: Your first comment stated that you would have accepted `std::array` as an answer, so maybe you were not familiar with it?  That's why I posted the comment concerning std::array.  As to your question not being good, I didn't downvote, so I have no insight on why it was downvoted.   Last, going to AI bots for answers when it comes to C++ --  Chatgpt and other bots are simply not trained well enough (yet) to give correct answers when it comes to C++ -- there have been many posts where an AI bot was used, and the poster got everything wrong and thus resorted to asking the question here.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I appreciate the response, thank you. I was familiar with it, but I'd rather have returned a raw pointer to the array, but coming from Java/C# it felt more natural to return a reference, because the array in `ColorData` is not expected to ever be `null` / `nullptr`. The thing is, that while not entirely correct, AI bots somewhat help understand pieces here and there and I sure as hell won't be copying everything without double-checking things I think are problematic. I didn't expect a potential gcc bug though. Also: this is by far not my first question on SO. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Normal array allocate in stack  memory, any function as well. So when you use reference of pop out stack you will got undefined behavior. That why heap memory is exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is not intrinsically wrong to return a reference to an array member. It is quite different from attempting to return an array from a free function. Additionally, GCC just uses a different syntax, and it looks like a bug to me but I need some language lawyer to confirm this. To make your code compile on gcc, use the following instead.

```
[[nodiscard]] const uint8_t (&getColor2() const override)[4];
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/xMqPzT1vc

Comment: Thank you - I don't understand why the override is where it is, but this seems the closest to what I'd like to have (which is: I'd like to make it obvious, that the array, that `getColor2()` returns, has exactly 4 items). I'll mark this as the correct answer I suppose. I'm really a newbie in regards to C/C++ so thank you for your explanation and patience!

Comment: This is a known GCC bug reported as [#84581](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84581).

Answer (score 1):

I would use `std::array<uint8_t, 4>`, see https://godbolt.org/z/h3TjxYv3b.

There is a pros - readability:

```
const std::array<uint8_t, 4>& getColor2() const; // is easier to read than
const uint8_t (&getColor2() const)[4];
```

`using arr = uint8_t[4]` also can be used: https://godbolt.org/z/Pbxhb8h3G.

```
arr& getColor2() const;
```

Comment: The other answer seems to be better suitable to the OP.

Comment: Still - thank you for your response, too, and your patience, of course. This response shows a couple more facets to returning arrays, that will never be null / unset (the `colorData` is always initialized when it's created and is `0,0,0,0` by default).