# Overriding a class method returning a constant reference to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, overriding

I have this code where MyClass derives from the iClass interface and has a method returning a constant reference to the member array arr:

```
#include <iostream>

class iMyClass
{
    public:
        virtual const int (&getDataRef())[100] = 0;
};

class MyClass : public iMyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass(): arr{}{};
        const int (&getDataRef())[100];
        void set() {arr[5] = 5;};
    private:
        int arr[100];
};

const int (&MyClass::getDataRef())[100]
{
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    MyClass a;
    const int (&brr)[100] = a.getDataRef();
    a.set();
    std::cout << brr[5];

    return 0;
}
```

This does what I expect (i.e. prints 5).

But the compilation fails if I add 'override' at the end of the declaration of getDataRef() in MyClass to indicate that the base class function is overriden:

```
    const int (&getDataRef())[100] override;
```

Console output:

```
main.cpp:21:34: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
   21 |     const int (&getDataRef())[100] override;
      |                                  ^
      |                                   ;
main.cpp:21:36: error: ‘override’ does not name a type
   21 |     const int (&getDataRef())[100] override;
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~
```

Anyone knows why? I could probably use a typedef to define the array, but I'd like to understand why it's not compiling. How can this be fixed without a typdef?

Comment: It should be `const int (&getDataRef() override)[100];`: https://godbolt.org/z/15Eoo575x. But really, use a typedef or better `std::array<int, 100>` instead. This is a syntactical mess, I doubt anyone can easily understand what is going on here.

Comment: When I see `const int (&getDataRef())[100];` I get a bit dizzy. What is the intent here? Why can't this be something simple like `const std::array<int, 100>&`?

Comment: or even simpler a `std::span<int, 100>`

Comment: `auto getDataRef() -> const int (&)[100] override` would be an alternative.

Comment: Possibly duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77567844 note that [GCC has bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84581)

Answer (score 1):

> It should be [`const int (&getDataRef() override)[100];`](https://godbolt.org/z/15Eoo575x). But really, use a `typedef` or better `std::array<int, 100>` instead. This is a syntactical mess, I doubt anyone can easily understand what is going on here.

–
Yksisarvinen