# Why is the reference count not 2?

Tags: c++, pointers, std, shared-ptr

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class type
{
public:
    type()
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
    ~type()
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    type* p = new type();

    std::shared_ptr<type> ptr1(p);

    std::shared_ptr<type> ptr2(p);

    int count = ptr2.use_count();
}
```

Two shared_ptrs are referencing the same raw pointer, so why is the ref count 1?

[image]

It refers to the same address.

Comment: Program [crahses here](https://godbolt.org/z/jbW46oW3a)

Comment: See `-fsanitize=undefined` with clang and [clang gives warning](https://godbolt.org/z/j6zvWvP19)

Comment: Because the constructors of `shared_ptr` that accept a raw pointer assume exclusive ownership.  Construct `std::shared_ptr<type> ptr2(ptr1)` to get the sharing behaviour you expect.   From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr  "The raw pointer overloads assume ownership of the pointed-to object. Therefore, constructing a shared_ptr using the raw pointer overload for an object that is already managed by a shared_ptr, such as by shared_ptr(ptr.get()) is likely to lead to undefined behavior, even if the object is of a type derived from std::enable_shared_from_this."

Comment: See this dupe: [Best way to protect from multiple shared_ptr to the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223895/best-way-to-protect-from-multiple-shared-ptr-to-the-same-object)

Comment: I would suggest avoid calling the constructor of `shared_ptr` that takes a raw pointer at all (there are cases where this can be useful, but you would already know it if it is the case). Always use factory functions like `std::make_shared`. It makes errors like this less likely to happen.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood how gifts and sharing works. If you have a car and tell person A "this car is now yours, but you must share it if somebody asks", and then you tell person B the same thing without mentioning that it's already A's car, A and B are both going to believe that the car has exactly one owner.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<type> ptr1(std::exchange(p, nullptr));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

> ```
> type* p = new type();
> ```

`p` is a raw owning pointer. Raw owning pointers should be avoided all together. Raw owning pointers have no support for managing ownership, it is all up to you.

Next,

> ```
> std::shared_ptr<type> ptr1(p);
> ```

you transfer ownership from `p` to `ptr1`. The shared pointer does support managing ownership. Internally it keeps a reference count when you share ownership *via this instance*.

Next,

> ```
> std::shared_ptr<type> ptr2(p);
> ```

you transfer ownership from `p` to `ptr2`. However, you did already transfer ownership away from `p`. There is already  a second seperate shared pointer that does own the object. `ptr2` cannot know about that already existing other shared pointer, because you transfer ownership from `p`. `p` is a raw pointer and has no support to manage ownership.

The reference count of both shared pointers is 1, because they both believe they would be the only owner of the object.

---

If you want to get a second shared pointer that shares ownership with an already existing shared pointer, you can make a copy:

```
type* p = new type();
std::shared_ptr<type> ptr1(p);
std::shared_ptr<type> ptr2(ptr1);
std::cout << ptr2.use_count();
```

In that code, `ptr1` and `ptr2` share the ownership of the object. Whichever pointer leaves the scope last will destroy the object. In your code both will attempt to destroy the object, because you made them both the sole owner of the object.

Smart pointers do not release you from having a clear concept of ownership, but rather they enable you to express it clearly in the code. You can still use them wrong, its just a little harder as compared to using raw pointers.